# removing tag outline from <a> tag in html

Tags: html, css

I have a  tag on an html page, inside the  tag I have an img tag, when I click an image a image scroller pops up and when i close the scroller the image now has an outline on it, which i can remove by pressing tab or clicking elsewhere, is there anyway to remove this outline?

Thanks,

```
<p><a class="group1" href="images/1.jpg"><img src="projectspic.jpg"/></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

write this:

```
a{
 outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS will do it:

```
.group1 {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```css
a.group1 { 
    outline: none; 
    border:none; 
}
```

Comment: sometime because of other CSS rules, this may get overriden, in that case you may want to use the pseudo-class a.group1:focus etc

Comment: Worth noting that it's an [accessibility best practice](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G183.html) to give a visual cue for focus.

Comment: as a UI developer, sometimes you will face problems explaining the same to the business guys who will not and refuse to understand such technical standards.  In such situations, I try to remove the "ugly" outline and set some other cue.

I'm working on this website http://whospent.com where you will notice that the outlines are replaced with a visual cue and lets user know about the focus of the cursor on page.  just open the site and press tab repeatedly you will observe that